# SpringBoot and Kubernetes error "IntegrationTest.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load.. IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder"

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I want to inject this value `greeting_from_environment_variable` from a ConfigMap in kubernetes.
But it is not passing the unit integration tests.

```
@Value("${greeting_from_environment_variable}")
String greeting;



org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encouragerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'greeting_from_environment_variable' in value "${greeting_from_environment_variable}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties
```

....

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'greeting_from_environment_variable' in value "${greeting_from_environment_variable}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver
```

....

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.531 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.dropaflame.encourage.EncourageApplicationIntegrationTest
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encouragerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'greeting_from_environment_variable' in value "${greeting_from_environment_variable}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'greeting_from_environment_variable'
```

...

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   EncourageApplicationIntegrationTest.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

The IntegrationTest class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class EncourageApplicationIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        ResponseEntity<List<Encouragement>> responseEntity;
        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("/all-quotes", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Encouragement>>(){});
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody()));
    }
}
```

To get around the error, I did a workaround:

```
@Value("${greeting_from_environment_variable:default}")
String greeting;
```

but this is not a solution IMHO

Answer (score 0):

As described in the question:

> To get around the error, I did a workaround:
>
> ```
> @Value("${greeting_from_environment_variable:default}")
> String greeting;
> ```